# Is there an online tester for xPath selectors?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I know there are some online regex evaluators.. very useful, matching in real time. They are like web applications of RegexBuddy.

I was wondering if there is a similar thing for xPath selectors? I am just learning them and it would be valuable to me.

Is there an online tester that allows you to input XML and then an xPath selector and match (live would be better, but I doubt someone has written a JavaScript interpreter?) them?

Thanks

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I notice that the only "online" checker in the answers seems a bit clunky. It requires submission to a server, and it doesn't handle namespaces properly.

I thought I could do better, and that such a tool would be quite useful, so I made one.  I realize it is slightly self-promoting to mention it here, but it does specifically answer the question, I think!

http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm

Mine can apply an xpath expression to an arbitrary XML document and display the results.  It can also beautify, or pretty-print an XML document, and apply an XSLT transformation to it.  All processing is done by the browser, and it should work in IE6+, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

Please let me know if you encounter any issues with it!

Comment: Why do I have to press refresh? It should use some AJAX magic! That, and displaying/highlighting only the matches. (Just like Rubular does for regex.)

Comment: Sorry, the "refresh" button does not actually refresh your browser, it merely re-executes the JavaScript rendering process.  I guess I should rename it, huh?  There is no AJAX because no XML is ever sent to the server at any time--it's processed 100% in JavaScript.  I will add highlighting when I have time; keep in mind this is a personal project for me. Nobody pays me for this! ;)

Comment: awesome little tool saves me having to download the xpath visualiser which seems to crash alot

Comment: Awesome tool. Is the source available ?

Comment: Sure is!  Right click on the page and select "View Source!"  ;)

There's no explicit license.  I'd appreciate it if you'd consider it to be under the same creative commons license as any other StackOverflow post.

The source is not exactly production quality, so caveat emptor.

Answer (score 37):

This is not an online tool; instead it's a Windows app, more along the lines of RegexBuddy, but for XPath.

[XPathVisualizer](http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com).

[screen shot http://i29.tinypic.com/1zwp5ix.jpg](http://i29.tinypic.com/1zwp5ix.jpg)

Comment: Wish I'd know about that a couple of years ago.

Comment: General observations: A good first exercise in producing a WinForms application.

Not too-advanced, with too restrictive platform requirements, and a little bit too late. 

The real XPathVisualizer has been around since the year 2000 with thousands of downloads each month. 

XPath is clearly not a good area in which to try to rediscover the wheel.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, I can understand being proud of your own project, but at least resolve that your site is flagged as malware!

Comment: @Aadvark: This is not "my site". Please, propose to host the XPath Visualizer and I might consider it. :)

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, I would if I could!

Comment: Not bad. I just wish it used some "AJAX magic" by auto-evaluating instead of making me hit Eval every few seconds :/

Comment: @ashes99 - it now has "AJAX magic".  Actually there's no Javascript at all, but it automatically evaluates the XPath as you type it. You need v1.3 to get that feature.

Answer (score 28):

**Edit**: The XPath Visualizer for IE now has **[a new, safer home](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)**, thanks to the kindness of Lars Huttar. Also **[there](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)** is the XPath Visualizer for FF.

**The XPath Visualizer has been available for more than 10 years and has helped thousands of people learn XPath the fun way. Available [for IE](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html) and [for FireFox](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)**.

**The XPath Visualizer is a popular tool for learning XPath by playing with XPath expressions**. Free and open source.

**Allows any XPath expression to be evaluated** against a given XML document and displays the results hi-lighted in the xml document (if they are node(s)) or in a separate box (if the results are atomic values).

**Allows xsl:variable-s to be defined and then used** in XPath expressions.

**Allows xsl:key-s to be defined and then referenced by key() functions** within XPath expressions.

Comment: warning, according to google the linked site contains malware:
http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?client=Firefox&hl=en-US&site=http://www.topxml.com/code/cod-422_9827_xpath-visualizer-for-the-mozilla-browser.aspx

Comment: I will be considering moving the download to a safe site. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Dimitre, Firefox version can be accessed from somewhere?

Comment: @Flack: It was on topxml.com (don't access it -- contains malware). I also have it, but since recently it stopped working on FF and I don't have an idea why and also no time to investigate. Do you want the code and to try make it working once again? They might have changed the way XSLT transformations are performed. The existing code was written around 2002-2003 and was working until recently.

Comment: @Dimitre, no obligations :), but I certainly would like to see the sources. Also, I consider you could publish it on github or sourceforge like XSelerator. I guess, stating that it needs to be updated is enough to get no unnecessary critics.

Comment: @Flack: Since some time the XPV is available at a safe site, thanks to Lars Hutar -- see the EDIT at the top of my answer. The download has always contained the source code. :)

Comment: @Dimitre, I guess you should remove "(warning: link not safe)" and link to Firefox version on topxml.

Comment: @Dimitre, and, is source code at huttar.net also actual for Firefox or it had major differences (while it was available and worked)?

Comment: @Flack: No, at huttar.net there is only the XPV for IE. Anyway, it seems that in the most current versions of FF, XPV is not working. Are you interested in getting the code and making it work again?

Comment: @Dimitre. In fact I am. It really messes with me to start IE just for XPV :)

Comment: @Flack: Then why don't you contact me (dnovatchev) on the mail provided by Google?

Comment: @Dimitre. Do you plan to include Firefox version with a safer link? It's still a firework of antivirus alerts :(

Comment: @Flack: I need to ask @LarsH first, it is his site. @LarsH, will you kindly allow me to put the FF version of the XPath Visualizer also there?

Comment: @Flack: The XPV for FF has been uploaded to Lars Huttar's site and the link in this answer has been updated accordingly.

Comment: @Flack: Yes, and thank *you* for helping to make this possible.

Comment: +1 For this collaborative behaviour.

Comment: The FireFox version doesn't work. Pressing 'process file' says [Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied"  code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"  location: "file:///C:/DOCUME~1/TCHIVE~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/XPathVisualizer/XPathMain.htm Line: 43"]

Comment: @TomChiverton: This, of course, means that you have unzipped the distribution archive in the wrong place -- try unzipping it into a directory, from which FF can open local .htm files.

Answer (score 17):

Yep! Try the [**XPath Checker**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1095) extension for Firefox. It's a handy tool.

Comment: XPath Visualizer didn't work for me in Firefox 3.5 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

Here is a nice one: http://www.xpathtester.com/

Comment: Although I've only tried simple xpath expressions, so far xpathtester has worked well for me too.

Comment: I've been working with it for a while and I really like it.  It has a Clean interface and instead of marking the results over the XML, it generates the resulting node/list/text.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Notepad++ with it's XMLTools plugin - it has xPath evaluator

Answer (score 2):

i use this one

http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php

Answer (score 1):

Here is one...

[XPath Query Expression Tool](http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I found the following tool the most helpful.

[Allans Online XPath Tester](http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx)

The other tools mentioned below either required a particular browser or had some issue with loading xml or using some of the more obscure XPath expressions I was using.  This tool did not.

Comment: If the tool I mentioned in my answer has such issues, please do let me know so I can fix it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Remove It Permanently](http://rip.mozdev.org/), a firefox extension available on AMO, has such visualization functions.  It would be nice if it had firebug type power for the slightly advanced adblocker.

[screenshot http://i49.tinypic.com/n65a3d.jpg](http://i49.tinypic.com/n65a3d.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Firefox, you can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) + [Firefinder](http://robertnyman.com/firefinder/), which enable you to filter elements based on XPath expressions, and even post the matched code to [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) in a snap.