# Extract Sales rank from a website

Tags: web-scraping, kindle

I am trying to extract Sales rank of kindle books from [this amazon site](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003XF1XOQ).

In the above case the sales rank is 3 (element name "`SalesRank`")

This is what i have tried till now

```
$xpath_kindle->query("//li[@id='SalesRank']")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use the this xpath: `//li[@id='SalesRank']/text()` and use regex to select the rank numeral.
Also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688323/is-there-an-online-tester-for-xpath-selectors) in SO where some really good tools are mentioned.