# XPath attribute value parsing

Tags: xml, xpath

I have simple XML structure like this:

```
<project>
  <frame>
    <object type="Circle" radius="5"/>
    <object type="Square" side ="4"/>
  </frame>
</project>
```

What path string should I use(XPath 1.0) to receive radius attribute's value of object, which type attribute is equal to "Circle".

```
/project/frame/object[@type="Circle"]/@radius
```

Is it correct?

**Edited**:
Yes, it is really correct, I've checked it using tools, that was adviced me in comments. But the string returned is:

```
 radius="5"
```

Are there any approach to receice only attribute value - "5"??

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: It certainly looks correct to me. Do you get an error from your toolset or not the right answer? What are you doing with the XPath expression?

Comment: I'm using C. I want to write XPath based XML parsing interface for ARM-core microcontroller. But I think programming language doesn't matter for this question.

Comment: Your xpath is good; your xml is less so (your `object` elements are unclosed)

Comment: @Christopher Creutzig, I just have little misunderstanding about XPath syntax.

Comment: Get yourself some tool that handles them (xml starlet, saxon, your browser, …) and play around with them then. :-)

Comment: [This might also be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688323/is-there-an-online-tester-for-xpath-selectors)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
doc("c:\temp\temp.xml")
/data(/project/frame/object[@type="Circle"]/@radius)
```